# Road bike commuting

Tags: commuter, parts, road, modification

I have a road bike (Orbea Aqua T23) on which many of the components are coming to the end of their lives.  As such I'm replacing most of them, and was wondering what people thought were good mods to make to a road bike to make it best suited for commuting?  Thanks!!!

Comment: I advise to single out components that really require replacement (broken, worn out) and get compatible new ones for the price you are willing to pay.

Comment: Without year component and number of speeds can't provide a good answer.

Comment: This question might be better answered in [chat] cos its not particularly defined.  Remember the [tour] which says SE is about a single question with multiple answers being up or downvoted.  This is more of a poll of opinions.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments say, if you're more specific, people can help you better.

That said, some general advice for a commuter bike:

1. Sturdier tyres, as wide as you can get away with in your frame. Ideally with puncture protection.
2. Fenders / mud guards. Can be had as clip-on, in case your bike frame doesn't support permanently mounted ones.
3. Lights. Essential. Here's where more information would be useful. If you have to replace the front wheel anyway, look to replace it with one that has a dynamo hub (you might need to ask a shop to build them for you). This way, you don't have to deal with battery lights. Otherwise, get battery lights.
4. Reflectors, front, rear, spokes. Cheap, and boost your visibility.

None of that, with the possible exception of the tyres and the front wheel, is, strictly speaking, a replacement for existing parts. Still, it's necessary if you want to commute in darkness or bad weather.

As for other replacements, this is mostly a guessing game since you don't tell us what needs replacing. So, in no particular order:

- Do you need the front gear shifter? If you can get away with only one chain ring, that's removing one potential source for trouble / extra maintenance. Note that this might necessitate a new crank. Don't know if you need that anyway.
- Cheap saddle if you have to park outdoors. Provided you like your old saddle, it's still in good working order, and you can use it better elsewhere.
- Hybrid clip-in / flat pedals. So you can wear "normal" shoes for shorter rides, and be clipped in for longer ones. That's assuming you're using roadbike-style clipless pedals at the moment (e.g. Look, SPD-SL, Time, Speedplay, [...]).

Comment: For commuting, if you want clipless, I would look at options in the MTB SPD lineup for pedals. You can get street and even business shoes that take a recessed cleat.

Comment: Obviously, it's a matter of taste but I'd not bother with a hub dynamo. USB-rechargeable LED lights don't require much dealing: they go a long time between charges, tell you when they need charging and can be recharged wherever you happen to be.

Comment: @mattnz - Clipless: yes, that's what I'd look at, too. Of course, we don't know if the questioner currently uses clipless pedals.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Hub dynamo is a bit of a luxury for a roadbike, especially if you have to have a custom-built wheel. On the other hand, it's the fire and forget solution: once it's set up, you never have to think about it again. LEDs last forever... Also, clip-on lights are more easily stolen if left on the bike than fixed ones. But, yes, it's a matter of taste, and both can be good solutions.